# Hue misconfiguration error

Tags: hadoop, hue

I am running Hadoop 2.6.0 on cdh5.4.2 in VM. After unexpected power cut I started my VM and found hue is not working, its not started properly and given the error

[image]

I restarted HUE using below command:

sudo service hue stop

sudo service hue start

But no use. I was not able to run hive/pig/sqoop. Please help me what to do to fix this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you restart all the hadoop services..

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana, I am new to HDP, Can you pls let me know the commands to restart hadoop services in CDH.

Comment: for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done

Comment: I tried to start the services, but no luck. Impala Editor is also not working now.

Comment: Can you check the status of all the service...

Comment: Here are the failed status services  Hadoop proxyserver is dead and pid file exists            
HBase master daemon is dead ...           
HBase Solr Indexer is dead ...            
Hive Server2 is dead  ...                  
Impala Server is dead ...                 
Sentry DB Store Service is ...       
Solr server daemon agent is not running                   
Spark history-server is not running                       
Spark master is not running                               
Spark worker is not running                               
zookeeper-server is not running.

Comment: remove the pid file and try to restart all the service again.

Comment: I have removed the relevant pids and restarted the services. But again same kind of listing is showing. Don't know where I am doing wrong.